# How to join a table with a small text dataset?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this:

```
// poses
+----+-------------+-------+
| id |  pos_number | value |
+----+-------------+-------+
| 1  | 10001       | NULL  |
| 2  | 10002       | NULL  |
+----+-------------+-------+
```

Also, I have raw data (excel file) like this:

```
10001 | x
10002 | y
```

As I said, it's an excel file that I can access as a text file and parse it by regex. I want to join that real table (`poses`) with raw data and then update that table. Something like this:

```
UPDATE poses p
JOIN ( ... ) temp_table ON p.pos_number = temp_table. ...
SET p.value = temp_table. ...
```

Anyway, in which syntax can I use a pure text as a join to a real table via MySQl query?

---

Here is the expected result:

```
// poses
+----+-------------+-------+
| id |  pos_number | value |
+----+-------------+-------+
| 1  | 10001       | x     |
| 2  | 10002       | y     |
+----+-------------+-------+
```

Comment: Is this a one-time script, or do you need a programmatic solution for regular executions/updates?

Comment: @Aron One time ..! Noted that I can make that text file in any form needed by Regex. Just I want to know, how can I make a temp table (inside the query) via some raw data.

Comment: Hi Martin - how many rows are expected to be updated in this activity? You could probably think about creating raw UPDATE queries directly from excel using String concat. You could also create a temp MySQL table from CSV (save Excel as CSV probably) and then do a JOIN.

Comment: I have done SQL statement building in Excel before with great success, but it looks like you may be able to use a LOAD DATA statement if you are dealing with a lot of data - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html

Answer (score 1):

If the text file is big and you want to do it fast, you should use `LOAD DATA` Statement to import a text file into MYSQL table:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html

Example (if you have a CSV file with header as first line):

```
  LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'file.csv'
  INTO TABLE db.table
  CHARACTER SET utf8mb4
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
  ENCLOSED BY '"'
  LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
  IGNORE 1 lines
```

Answer (score 0):

I did it this way:

Pattern:

```
([^  ]+)  ([^  ]+)\n
```

Replacement:

```
select "$1" as pos_number, "$2" as value union \n
```

Removing the last `union`

Query:

```
UPDATE poses p join (
<result above>
) x on x.pos_number = p.pos_number
SET p.value = x.value
```